# send ECHO and then HEADER()

Tags: php

I have a flash form that sends info to my database though a php file.
The problem is that the flash forms needs an echo response, but i also have to send header(Location:with_url_vars)
... and i just found out that his doesn't work => can't send echo before header()

I think i can't use a javascript or meta-refresh either, because only my swf file executes my php file... so the browser of the user will never reach my php file.

And i also can't send the echo after header(Loaction:...) because once i leave, I can't get back to my echo.

Any ideas what i can do to solve this problem?
THANX
Mavi

Comment: Whats the point of 'echoing' when you are changing the location? Infact you must look carefully in your requirements.

Comment: Just put the `echo` after all `header` calls

Comment: It sounds like you haven't thought this through? It shouldn't be necessary to send a location header to a flash object, as this will be completely hidden from the user anyway. Maybe it would help if you elaborate why you need to redirect the page?

Answer (score 0):

Crude, but turn on PHP's output buffering at the start of the script

```
ob_start();
```

Bonus points for having this at the end of your script

```
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: This is unnecessary - If the header() is called as the first thing in the script, output is still generated and shown.

Comment: I'm aware of this, and by the sounds of it the code needs reimplementation, I'm replying with a work around to the assumed "headers sent" issue.